# XHR2 upload using Drupal 7's ajax framework

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to implement [XHR level 2](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2) (file API upload) using Drupal 7's JQuery $.ajax implementation. I've got the feeling I'm almost there.

First of all, I got XHR.send() working according to orginal example on [HTML5 demos](http://html5demos.com/dnd-upload). But now, I want to use [Drupal 7's built in ajax framework](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/group/ajax/7).

I found [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437544/xhr-level2-with-jquery-for-file-upload) [examples](http://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2012/08/21/html5-file-upload-with-progress-bar-using-jquery) how do this with JQuery but I can't get it working for Drupal 7 with a custom ajax responce. I also found a related (D8) discussion about this on [drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1843220).

Here's the code, which returns a ajax error "Illegal invocation". Probably because formData is not in a proper format?

```
    // 'files' below is a correct object with at least one file

    var file = files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('file', files[0]);

    // element_settings: see ajax.js in drupal
    var element_settings = {};

    element_settings.progress = { 'type': 'none' }; 
    element_settings.url = '/mymodule/save/ajax';
    element_settings.data = file;
    element_settings.cache = false; 
    element_settings.contentType = file.type;
    element_settings.processData = false;
    element_settings.submit = {
      'savedata': formData
    };

    element_settings.xhr = function() {
      myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
      if (myXhr.upload) {
        myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlerFunction, false);
      } else {
        console.log("Upload progress is not supported.");
      }
      return myXhr;
    };


    var base = '#myelement';
    ajax = new Drupal.ajax(base, $('#myelement'), element_settings); 
    ajax.eventResponse($(ajax.element));
```

On the server site, I'm using a menu hook with ajax_deliver as delivery callback.
This works, but I can't access $_FILES in the same way which is possible if you use xhr.send().

By, the way, I'm aware this only works in modern browsers. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Does jQuery's `$.ajax` even know how to send a `FormData`? If it doesn't, neither will Drupal's `Drupal.ajax`...

Comment: Yes, if `options.processData = false` and `options.data = FormData`.

Comment: Yes, that is one of the workarounds mentioned in the links (under "examples") in the description.

Comment: I didn't read all that =) I was just thinking out loud. The problem won't be to make jQuery do what you want. The problem will be making Drupal.ajax and its messed up pageState 'system' do what you want. I've tried this once too. You should inspect a normal 'ajax' file upload. You'll give up soon enough ;)

Comment: Yes, I suspect it might be impossible to do this unless you do some serious hacking in Ajax.js and ajax.inc.

Comment: Okay, got a little further with this. It seems to me Jquery Ajax is called at line 254 in ajax.js:

`ajax.beforeSerialize(ajax.element, ajax.options);`

`$.ajax(ajax.options);`

And all the evil doing is done by the `beforeSerialize` function. filedata is not really expected or allowed by that function? Which in turn causes the illegal invocation error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your approach is flawed. You should use as much of Drupal's ajax system as possible, even though is wildly uncomprehensible and weird. Don't create your own Drupal.ajax object. Let Drupal handle that and the events and triggers that come with that.

Then there are only 2 problems left:

1. Don't create an iframe and a fake form and submit that. Use Ajax.
2. Don't serialize and preprocess that request. Use only what I'm giving you.

They're combined in `jquery.form.js` apparently. So all you have to do, is override where `ajax.form.ajaxSubmit(ajax.options);` is called: `Drupal.ajax.prototype.eventResponse`.

[The result inside my failed-attempt-module.](http://drupalcode.org/sandbox/rudiedirkx/1595094.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/Drupal.ajax.prototype.eventResponse.js)

It's an override of `Drupal.ajax.prototype.eventResponse`. I've added everything inside `if ( 'FormData' in window )`

My original plan (as the module name says) was to make all file fields drop containers for HTML5 File drag/drop. My approach was flawed too. I think with this approach, it's not so difficult. Just extend the `FormData` object at the right time.